# angularjs $location.path not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs location path and facing very strange problem..

my relocate function:

```
        $scope.relocate = function(chat_id) {
        $location.path('/chat/' + chat_id);
    };
```

in the next code:

```
    <div class="scrollable-content">
    <div class="recent-chat"  ng-click="relocate({{recent_chat.id}})">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" class="user-icon" />
        <h2>{{recent_chat.mate.display_name}}</h2>
        <p>{{recent_chat.last_message_content}}</p> 
        <img src="./img/fb.png" class="fb-icon" alt="Facebook User" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div masonry load-images="false" class="chat-list"">
        <div class="masonry-brick chat-item" ng-repeat="chat in chatlist" ng-class="{unread: chat.unread==true}" ng-click="relocate({{chat.id}})">
            <img src="./img/usericon.png" class="user-icon" />
            <img src="./img/newmessage.png" class="new-message-icon" alt="New Message" />
            <h2>{{chat.mate.display_name}}</h2>
            <p>{{chat.last_message_content}}</p>
            <img src="./img/fb.png" class="fb-icon" alt="Facebook User" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

relocate function works only in the chat-list class block, but not working in the recent-chat block.

when I click the recent-chat div, it takes me to chat/undefined, altough when i inspect the element it gives the correct value for {{recent_chat.id}}.

but when I click a chat-item class block, it works as expected.

Comment: Did you try without interpolation? `ng-click="relocate(recent_chat.id)"` Well you really do not need an interpolation there. Also where is recent_chat coming from, with the displayed code it is very difficult to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

needed to remove interpolation. thanks to @PSL for answer in comment